# emacs M-e doesn't work properly in tex-mode

Tags: emacs, latex, nlp, punctuation, auctex

I'm using emacs and auctex to write LaTeX documents. For some reason, M-e doesn't move to the end of the sentence in tex-mode as it did when I went through the tutorial. It moves to the end of the paragraph. (That is, it moves to just before the next double line break)

What is wrong? Do I need to turn on/off some mode to skip to the next full stop? How do I check which modes are active?

Comment: `C-h m` will list the currently active modes (that is `describe-mode`).

Comment: this doesn't work for me either-- emacsW32 on WinXP. :(

Comment: Since this is an emacs question, rather than a programming question, I suppose I should have asked it at superuser.com rather than here...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I noticed that the same happens in my Emacs. The problem is that the variable `sentence-end-double-space` is set to `t`. This means that Emacs expects a sentence to end with a double space. By setting to `nil` things work properly, i.e., Emacs recognizes a period followed by a single space as the end of sentences.

Comment: To change variable type M-x set-variable RET sentence-end-double-space RET nil RET

Comment: A Q about setting it up in an even more complex way: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4754547/94687 -- though as for me personally, I doubt that it makes much sense to try to make Emacs match sentences in an even more delicate/smart way (false positives are not horrible if it's about interactive editing).

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to check is what <kbd>M-e</kbd> is bound to.  In tex-mode, for me, it is bound to `forward-sentence`.  You find this out by <kbd>C-h k M-e</kbd>.

It sounds as though it's bound to `forward-paragraph`, in which case I'd check your .emacs file to see if you've got any overrides in tex-mode hooks, or other things.  You can also try running without your .emacs: `emacs -q`, and seeing what <kbd>M-e</kbd> is bound to (to determine if it truly is your .emacs).  You can also start without the site lisp file `emacs -q --no-site-file` - in case your administrators have added anything.